# filling in daily values with 1 monthly value excel

Tags: excel

I have the following spreadsheet:

```
date    monthly value       Date    daily value
12/1/1947   0.089851024     12/1/1947   
1/1/1948    0.095282146     12/2/1947   
2/1/1948    0.075909091     12/3/1947   
3/1/1948    0.068181818     12/4/1947   
4/1/1948    0.085193622     12/5/1947   
5/1/1948    0.08740942      12/8/1947   
6/1/1948    0.086369771     12/9/1947   
7/1/1948    0.089285714     12/10/1947  
8/1/1948    0.069614711     12/11/1947  
9/1/1948    0.063291139     12/12/1947  
10/1/1948   0.054206418     12/15/1947  
11/1/1948   0.032037591     12/16/1947  
12/1/1948   0.015625        12/17/1947  
1/1/1949    0.014364174     12/18/1947
```

I want to fill every daily value with the respective month value, so for example every day in January 1948 daily value would be 0.09528214. How would I do this for dates spanning from 1948 to the present?

Comment: why is 195802 January 1958?

Comment: I'm not sure, I pulled this data directly from an article's sources. Is there an easy way to convert it? Nothing seems to work.

Comment: please adjust your test data to show your true needs.

Comment: updated the test data, every date is now consistently MDY

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Vlookup:

```
=VLOOKUP(C2,A:B,2,TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: @Jeeped I assumed: `I have a column of daily dates` that it meant daily and so MDY.  But it will work either way.

Comment: @Jeeped maybe the source from whence the OP got the data was that way.

Comment: @ÉvaristeGalois if the dates are true dates then the formula will work regardless of format.

Comment: I've converted the dates to both be MDY for consistency, how would this formula change?

Comment: See my comment above.  If it is a true date then it does not matter the formatting. @ÉvaristeGalois

Comment: Both seem to be true dates (if the value in the number field being date implies that), however this does not work when the monthly values are changed from YYYYMM to MMDDYYYY, am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You can use excel worksheet formulas: `=INDEX(MATCH())`

So if your daily date is in Column D, your Monthly values are A and B, then in column E you would:

`=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(DATE(YEAR(D2), MONTH(D2), 1),A:A,0))`